# process pubsub messages in constant rate. Using streaming and serverless

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

The scenario:
I have thousands of requests I need to issue each day.

I know the number at the beginning of the day and hopefully I want to send all the data about the requests to pubsub. Message per request.

I want to make the requests in constant rate. for example if I have 172800 requests, I want to process 2 in each second.

The ultimate way will involved pubsub push and cloud run.

Using pull with long running instances is also an option.

Any other option are also welcome.

I want to avoid running in a loop and fetch records from a database with limit.
This is how I am doing it today.

Comment: You can try using batch and flow control settings for fine-tuning Pub/Sub performance which will help in processing messages at a constant rate.
For more information you can refer to this [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/pub-sub-flow-control-batching-9ba9a75bce3b). Please let me know if it’s helpful.

Comment: Hi @ZAky, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use batch and flow control settings for fine-tuning Pub/Sub performance which will help in processing messages at a constant rate.

**Batching**

A [batch](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching), within the context of Cloud Pub/Sub, refers to a group of one or more messages published to a topic by a [publisher](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#publisher-subscriber-relationships) in a single publish request. Batching is done by default in the [client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) or explicitly by the user. The purpose for this feature is to allow for a higher throughput of messages while also providing a more efficient way for messages to travel through the various layers of the service(s). Adjusting the batch size (i.e. how many messages or bytes are sent in a publish request) can be used to achieve the desired level of throughput.

Features specific to batching on the publisher side include `setElementCountThreshold()`, `setRequestByteThreshold()`, and `setDelayThreshold()` as part of `setBatchSettings()` on a publisher client (the naming varies slightly in the different client libraries). These features can be used to finely tune the behavior of batching to find a better balance among cost, latency, and throughput.

Note: The maximum number of messages that can be published in a single batch is 1000 messages or 10 MB.

An example of these batching properties can be found in the [Publish with batching](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publisher-batch-settings) settings documentation.

**Flow Control**

[Flow control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#flow_control) features on the subscriber side can help control the unhealthy behavior of tasks on the pipeline by allowing the subscriber to regulate the rate at which messages are ingested. These features provide the added functionality to adjust how sensitive the service is to sudden spikes or drops of published throughput.

Some features that are helpful for adjusting flow control and other settings on the subscriber are `setMaxOutstandingElementCount()`, `setMaxOutstandingRequestBytes()`, and `setMaxAckExtensionPeriod()`.

Examples of these settings being used can be found in the [Subscribe with flow control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-subscriber-flow-settings) documentation.

For more information refer to this [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/pub-sub-flow-control-batching-9ba9a75bce3b).

If you are having long running instances as subscribers, then you will need to set relevant FlowControl settings for example `.setMaxOutstandingElementCount(1000L)`

Once you have set it to the desired number (for example 1000), this should control the maximum amount of messages the subscriber receives before pausing the message stream, as explained in the code below from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#:%7E:text=%2F%2F%20The%20subscriber%20will,conditions%20is%20met):

```
// The subscriber will pause the message stream and stop receiving more messsages from the
    // server if any one of the conditions is met.
    FlowControlSettings flowControlSettings =
        FlowControlSettings.newBuilder()
            // 1,000 outstanding messages. Must be >0. It controls the maximum number of messages
            // the subscriber receives before pausing the message stream.
            .setMaxOutstandingElementCount(1000L)
            // 100 MiB. Must be >0. It controls the maximum size of messages the subscriber
            // receives before pausing the message stream.
            .setMaxOutstandingRequestBytes(100L * 1024L * 1024L)
            .build();
```

Comment: I think it will not work. For example if I have 24 messages in the beginning of the day, I want 1 message to be processed each hour. If I have 24000 messages I want 1000 per hour. I don't understand how a combination of the above settings will achieve that.

Comment: Hi @ZAky, I have edited my answer as per your comment. If it’s not relevant to your use case, please provide more information and clarify on your use case and explain why this isn't a sufficient solution so I can understand it better.